# Debian battery jumps from 30 to 0

Tags: debian, battery

While my laptop is on the battery and reaches 30% (sometimes 32 or 36), it jumps to zero and shuts down after 1 minute. and as i plug in the AC adapter, it shows 30 again. even once on Ac it jumped from 70% to 100%.

this problem didn't seem to exist before, it's been a month i've seen this. what should i do about this? is this a bug or my laptop's problem?

OS: Debian 10 (buster), DE: gnome, Laptop: DELL Latitude 7480

Comment: This sounds like a hardware issue with the laptop. Battery charge measurement isn't a function of your OS, it's a function of your hardware.

Comment: I concur. The behavior you're describing might indicate that your battery is faulty and needs a replacement.